# cant get rid of mysterious links the header

Tags: html, css

So my problem is that i cant remove links from "username" and "password"
Can anyone help? Its my first week coding and I have searched everywhere.

```css
 #top_logo {
   width: 80px;
   height: 80px;
   float: left;
 }
 #top_nav {
   float: left;
 }
 #top_nav ul li {
   float: left;
   padding: 30px 30px;
 }
 #top_nav ul li a {
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 #kirjautuminen {
   float: left;
   padding: 30px 10px 30px 100px;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 #headerspace_1 {
   clear: both;
 }
```

```html
<header>
  <img id="top_logo" src="icon_tab.png" />
  <nav id="top_nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://www.google.fi">Main</li>
    <li><a href="https://www.yahoo.com">Classes</li>
    <li><a href="https://www.hs.fi">About us</li>
    <li><a href="https://www.yle.fi">Contact</li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <form id="kirjautuminen">
   Username: <input type="text" name="username">
   Password: <input type="password" name="password">
   <input type="submit" value="Kirjaudu">
  </form>
  <div id="headerspace_1"></div>
 </header>
```

Comment: What do you mean "links"? Can you please clarify the problem your having and what you expect it should be doing?

Answer (score 4):

You need to close your anchor/hyperlink tags in the navbar.

```
<nav id="top_nav">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.fi">Main</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.yahoo.com">Classes</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.hs.fi">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.yle.fi">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```